# Cannot resolve symbol MathUtils

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I started a new project on `Android Studio`, targeting `API 26`, and did nothing but to add the following line:

`import android.util.MathUtils;`

and got the error: `Cannot resolve symbol MathUtils`

Here's my `MainActivity.java`:

```
package com.example.HeyJude.test2;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.MathUtils;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

And my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.HeyJude.test2"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

I tried using `File > Invalidate Caches` (with restart), but it didn't help. Any other ideas?

Comment: You aren't using IdRes anywhere

Comment: @cricket_007, your'e right, it should be `MathUtils`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you search for it, did you mean this?

```
android.support.v4.math.MathUtils
```

Comment: Well, I guess so. Why, then, when I step into the source file `ListView.java`, I see `import android.util.MathUtils;`, and so I get the error `Cannot resolve symbol MathUtils`?

Comment: What are you trying to use this class for?

Comment: I don't, actually. It is when I stepped inside the source code of `ListView.java` where I see it is imported, but is marked in red and can't be resolved (along with other packages, like `android.annotation.IdRes`, `android.annotation.NonNull`, `com.android.internal.R` and some others). So that's, basically, my real problem - trying to step into android source code files, and getting everything marked in red.

Comment: If there aren't errors in your code, then you shouldn't  need to worry about those, right?

Comment: Well, I just want to fix it so I can step in the correct source files - which I apparently don't have. Never mind though, I guess it's an issue for a different post.

Comment: Well, `MathUtils` is open-sourced. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/util/MathUtils.java  And you do need to use the SDK Manager to download the sources separately.